# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,id) - shows NPE to decode image from drawable

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I use this method and it works every time if the file is xml and fails if it is in any other format.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);
```

below will work as it has xml,

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
```

there is test.PNG image on drawable folder and it wont work:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
```

---

> what is missing in this code to support decoding other format?
>
> > I am not specifically scaling the bitmap on test image and it is small too.

---

### [image]

Here is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.ram.myapplication, PID: 12759
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1083)
                                                                               at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1139)
                                                                               at com.example.ram.myapplication.MySurfaceView.drawSomething(MySurfaceView.java:96)
                                                                               at com.example.ram.myapplication.MySurfaceView$1.surfaceCreated(MySurfaceView.java:69)
                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:608)
                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:96)
                                                                               at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:185)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Edit :
I had to change the directory. Found somewhere  - Drawable folder cant be used. So had to use raw folder.

Comment: what is there on line number 108

Comment: and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Add code of `MySurfaceView`.

Comment: Please review this with updated logcat.

Comment: Check for canvas null

Comment: Canvas is not null and it works if I change the 'R.drawable.test' file to one with xml format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test, options);
```

if `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;`

If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

Hope it will work!!

Comment: It still cant draw anything except '.xml' files. It shows error as shown in logcat if it has other format than xml. I couldnt solve it yet.

Comment: I used other folder than the drawable one.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try putting your png images into some assets folder and access it something like below.

```
try {
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
InputStream open = manager.open("ic_launcher_background.png");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```